# Hide/Show div without affecting the inner elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

### The Basic Issue:

After hidden Parent is made `:visible`, it's children are remaining "*invisible*"

---

I have the HTML as following

```
    <div class="root">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <div>
        <p>description</p>
        <div>Sub one description</div>
        <div>
          <table>
            <tbody><tr><td><div>Flag</div></td></tr></tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>
```

When I use `.root {display:none;}` or `$('.root').slideUp(500);` the inner div and inner TD element are made display as none. So when I expand the root or make `.root{display:block;}` or `$('.root').slideDown(500);` the inner div and TD are not shown. Is it possible to hide and show the full root div without affecting the inner elements.

I tried `$('.root').hide();` and `$('.root').css('height','0');` and animate function in jquery nothing works out. Please help me in hiding and showing the root completely but without affecting the inner elements style. Thanks in advance.

Edited:

I have to hide the child elements also but when i shown the root the child elements should also be showed. Now the child elements are not shown.

Comment: Ya'll arn't reading the question. The problem is the inner elements are staying hidden even after `.show` and whatnot. There's something more going on here we cant see. Please show us you css and JS

Comment: @VoidKing Obviously since he tried to use different jQuery methods...

Comment: I can't believe someone upvoted this question... Did he sign in with a different account and upvote himself or something?

Comment: I am trying to implement this on a page which has 1000 lines of CSS and jquery. So not able to figure out the exact problem.

Comment: @VoidKing I upvoted it to give him time and chance to edit his question and give us details. He has a real issue, give him a chance, stop negging because you gave an incorrect answer

Comment: There's probably _something else_ in the CSS (or js?) somewhere that triggers the child to not be shown. [Otherwise it should work](http://jsfiddle.net/Zn63m/)

Comment: steps to debugging: YOU isolate the problem; search the internet (and SO) for the solution thoroughly; post question if you're unable to find a solution

Comment: @SpYk3HH The only reason I gave an incorrect answer is because he didn't know how to right the question properly. His edit is a little better but still unclear. What's your primary language, since it's apparently not English?

Comment: "I have to hide the child elements also"...does this mean that you hide each child element individually? In that case you also need to make them visible again individually.

Comment: @VoidKing It is English, And I made the edit. I had no trouble at all reading his question, which is why I requested more info from him.

Comment: @SpYk3HH You would think that. Anyway, whatever, moving on to bigger and better questions. Peace :)

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem here, your problem must be something else hiding your childs. Can't you share some code?

The explained problem works just fine here:

http://jsfiddle.net/48xKS/

```
$('.root').slideUp(500);

setTimeout(function() {
      $('.root').slideDown(500); 
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Finally someone who reaD the question! I'm so proud of you! Now if we can get the author to give us more info, like css and layout. I have a feeling this is either CSS or "order of fire" issue. +1 to you for "reading" the question!

Comment: I'm just sick of people on here not "Reading the question" and then trying to answer it. I've had 2 questions recently shutdown because of flagging as "repost" and people giving me answers ... that i already had in my question! If they would have taken the time to READ the question, they'd have found it wasn't a repost, nor were their answers helpful since I was already using that exact structure!

Answer (score 0):

I think you must not use **display:block** to show the node.

Use the following to hide:

```
$('.root').css('display','none');
```

and the following to show:

```
$('.root').css('display','');
```

by this way i think it will not affect your html when root is shown again

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I tried your solution. But it is not working out for me.

Comment: Check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/cdNVF/ I have added hide/show button. It is working, but may be in your case the CSS is creating some issue. It would be nice if you can share your CSS code over jsFiddle